# Python resize image so that height and width are the same

Tags: python, image, resize

I run the below:

Import PIL

```
    img = img.resize(106,106)
    img.save(img_path)
```

It makes the width 100 and height 106.  How do I get it to make them both the same?

Answer (score 2):

Put the values in parentheses because the method expects a tuple argument with two integers to specify the width and height.

```
img = img.resize((106,106))
img.save(img_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

img = img.resize((106,106))
img.save(img_path)